# Certificates in AWS IoT: Public and Private keys

Tags: mqtt, iot, node-red, client-certificates, aws-iot

So I'm relatively new to AWS and IoT on the whole. The concept of certificates seems to be quite confusing to me, especially the way AWS seems to handle it.

My Scenario:

I'm using a raspberry pi to publish data and a node-red on my PC. They are connected by AWS (which is the MQTT broker in my case I suppose). Based on my understanding it is such that, the Private key is to be kept private and the public key can be freely distributed.

My Question:

So when registering a "Thing" with AWS, it gave me a Private/Public key pair, a certificate, and a root CA (using the "One-click certificate creation" process). Now, my understanding is that, the Private key should be kept with the raspberry pi (end device) only and is not to be shared. And it's able to connect to AWS and publish the temperature data.
Now if I am to receive the messages on my node-red (MQTT In node) on my PC, should I use the public key there (since it can be freely distributed)? Does this mean that, I can distribute my Public key to as many people and they'll all be able to subscribe to my Raspberry Pi's temprature readings ?

P.S. I tried out the Public key and it doesn't seem to work. Please help me out here, as to what is necessary on the subscribing/receiving end, in terms of keys and certificates. An explanation would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access thing by using only public key  from your application (Node Red).

Moreover, If you want to access IoT thing using *certificate* based approach (out of 3 approaches mentioned later on), you may create separate key pairs and certificate, and can  attach a certificate to thing that you want to access.

If I elaborate more, the certificate will be attached to policy (in your case Node Red IoT Policy), and policy would define authorization.

To make certificate attachment mandatory to IoT thing, you need to use [thing policy variable](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/thing-policy-variables.html)–iot:Connection.Thing.IsAttached where sample policy is [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/thing-policy-examples.html)

In summary, your thing would have 2 certificates attached where one is from firmware device and another one is from Node Red application.

*Concepts*:

In general, there are [3 ways to access](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/client-authentication.html) AWS IoT things.

1. X.509 client certificates
2. IAM users, groups, and roles
3. Amazon Cognito identities